# For a row with five elements, how to let second and forth element fill remain width evenly?

Tags: html, css

For example, I have 5 elements:

```
  <span style="width:100%;">
    <div>1111111111</div>
    <div style="width:100%;background-color:red;">2222222222</div>
    <div>3333333333</div>
    <div style="width:100%;background-color:red;">4444444444</div>
    <div>5555555555</div>
  </span>
```

Which I want them to be enclosed into a row, and then the second and forth element expand to fill the remain width, which the second and forth element would have same width. How can I do it?

I tried:

```html
<table style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="white-space:nowrap;">1111111111</td>
    <td style="width:100%;background-color:red;">2222222222</td>
    <td style="white-space:nowrap;">3333333333</td>
    <td style="width:100%;background-color:red;">4444444444</td>
    <td style="white-space:nowrap;">5555555555</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Which the second element expands to "bully" the forth element, which is not working. (Note: it is not necessary to use table, just I think I can achieve the result and then use it, but stills not working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `flex-grow` and `flex-basis` to achieve this. Note that the second and fourth divs below are the same width as each other, even when the remaining space in the parent is different.

```html
<div style="display: flex; width: 200px;">
  <div style="background: red;">1</div>
  <div style="background: orange; flex-basis: 1; flex-grow: 1;">2</div>
  <div style="background: yellow;">3</div>
  <div style="background: green; flex-basis: 1; flex-grow: 1;">4</div>
  <div style="background: blue;">5</div>
</div>
<br/>
<div style="display: flex; width: 200px;">
  <div style="background: red;">1111</div>
  <div style="background: orange; flex-basis: 1; flex-grow: 1;">2</div>
  <div style="background: yellow;">3333</div>
  <div style="background: green; flex-basis: 1; flex-grow: 1;">4</div>
  <div style="background: blue;">5555</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the other three cells to a common width and leave 2 and 4 undefined. The result will be that both 2 and 4 will fill the remaining space equally.

```html
<table style="width:100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width:10%;">1111111111</td>
    <td style="background-color:red;">2222222222</td>
    <td style="width:10%;">3333333333</td>
    <td style="background-color:red;">4444444444</td>
    <td style="width:10%;">5555555555</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```